# textbox with numbers only but also pasting, copying, and selecting

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new in VB and got stuck on (i think) easy problem. I have a text box thats allows only numbers:

```
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 49 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

from 1 to 9. But this box doesnt allows me to paste, copy, and select text...how can i change it? I know that KeyCode for Control is 17, and for 'V' is 86, but have no idea how to use it...
thanks for any help

Comment: Use a [**`NumericUpDown`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. It's limited to numbers only and supports copying, pasting, cutting, etc.

Comment: You don't need to add any extra fancy code to copy/paste within a textbox, that ability is inherent in any text field. If you are unable to copy/paste, it's likely because you're trapping all keypresses that aren't numbers or backspaces. If control c/v are pressed, but your code handles them, then the keyboard messages never bubble up out of your application for the system to fire a copy/paste message. You need to find a different way to limit your textbox text to numbers

Comment: thank you Visual Vincent and  soohoonigan  for help! one more question, is there any way to delete the scrollbars from the NumericUpDown field? i cant find this option in properties...

Comment: Yes, you could hide them; there's a thread describing how to do that [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?732031-hide-spin-buttons-in-NUD). But personally I tend to go with an approach similar to Arun Kumar's answer, except I add more code to control the cursor position. Currently his will kick the cursor to the end no matter what you do, even if you're deleting the first character for example.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with KeyPress is that it calls only one KeyPress at a time. Hence multiple selections such as Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C would not work. Instead of flagging it under KeyPress, call the TextChanged. Add the below mentioned and the issue should be resolved. Copy, Paste and Selecting would now work as normal.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TextBox2.Text, "[^\d]", "")    'Removes all character except numbers
    TextBox2.Select(TextBox2.Text.Length + 1, 1)    'To bring the textbox focus to the right
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the `Select` call really needed? That puts the selection at the very end every time you input even a valid character. Isn't leaving the selection where it is enough?

Comment: I added it just to prevent the focus to be at the left end of the textbox, when you type an alphabets or special characters.

Comment: You could temporarily store the previous `SelectionStart` and then reset it and set `SelectionLength` to 0 after the Regex replace. That would keep the selection where it was before.

Answer (score 1):

If you necessarily want a `TextBox` you could combine the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events in order to block anything that isn't numbers while manually allowing Copy, Paste, Cut, etc.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = False AndAlso Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False 'Verify if input is a number or a control character (such as Backspace).
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    Dim TargetTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True 'Start by blocking all key presses.

    Select Case e.KeyData 'In order to not block some standard keyboard shortcuts.
        Case Keys.Control Or Keys.C 'Copy
            TargetTextBox.Copy()
        Case Keys.Control Or Keys.X 'Cut
            TargetTextBox.Cut()
        Case Keys.Control Or Keys.V 'Paste
            TargetTextBox.Paste()
            TargetTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox2.Text, "[^\d]", "")
        Case Keys.Control Or Keys.A 'Select all.
            TargetTextBox.SelectAll()
        Case Else
            e.SuppressKeyPress = False 'Allow all other key presses to be passed on to the KeyPress event.
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Pardon the unintentional similar Regex, Arun Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me , write the below code on textbox keypress event

Try

```
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 13 AndAlso Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 AndAlso Not IsNumeric(e.KeyChar) AndAlso (e.KeyChar <> Chr(22)) Then
            MsgBox("Please enter numeric values", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        pObj.WriteErrorLog(Me.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message, ex, True)
    End Try
```